# Getting different results with same Aggregation MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing this aggregation in Robo3T :

```
db.getCollection('Tweets').aggregate([
  {"$match": {"ownerId": "5c8d2ce116c7f85377df590a"}}
, {"$match": {"topic": "topic_A"}}
, {"$match": {"timestamp" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")
                            , "$lte" : ISODate("2020-02-05T23:59:59.000Z") 
                            } 
             }
  }
,{"$count": "totalData"}
])
```

The total of Documents is 5742.
Now i am doing the same aggregation in a short program that i wrote using MongoDB driver

this is the code:

```
public void countMonthData() {
        LocalDateTime start = YearMonth.now().atDay(1).atStartOfDay();
        LocalDateTime end = YearMonth.now().atDay(5).atStartOfDay().plusSeconds(86399);
        MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("ownerId").is("5c8d2ce116c7f85377df590a"));
        MatchOperation matchTopic = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("topic").is("topic_A"));
        MatchOperation matchDates = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("timestamp").gte(start).lte(end));
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, matchTopic, matchDates);
        System.out.println(agg);
        AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Tweets.class, Document.class);
        System.out.println("size: " + result.getMappedResults().size());
    }
```

When i print the number of documents retrieved from the aggregation i got 5100 Documents

Why do i have different results?

---

---

---

Finally find the error, I change the time zone for the variable start and end but for some reason MongoDB don't accept the new time zone, i have to change the time in the jvm for my project with this configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        System.out.println("Date in UTC: " + new Date().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Timezone difference?  You appear to be using UTC in Robo3T and local time with the driver.

Comment: Had the same idea, so i change the time zone but i'm getting the same results :(

Comment: Try running the [profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/profile/index.html#profile) database command, setting both `profile` and `slowms` to 0, then run the aggregation from both the driver and Robo3T.  You should see an entry in the mongod log that contains the details of the aggregation that was run.  Hopefully you will be able to see the difference there.